# Dynamic Json variable to feed Invoke-Restmethod

Tags: json, powershell, azure

I was able to pass the dynamic json object if the object creation code is in single line.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType "application/json" -Method Post -Body '{ "name" : "azurefunctionapp2email", "appname": "Applicationnamehere", "requestedBy" : "requestedby", "reqdate" : "requestdate", "status" : "Successfully Deployed", "AppsCount" : "2" }' `
    -Uri “https://implementurihere"
```

Since the dynamic JSON object in real world need be longer, I seperated created with new line `and referenced in the above as below. But new line shift` causes the json to break. I tried to pipe to `ConvertTo-Json` function and then found the output to hold '`\r\n' getting introduced:

```
$body = '{ "name" : "azurefunctionapp2email", `
       "appname": "Applicationnamehere", `
       "requestedBy" : "requestedby", `
       "reqdate" : "requestdate", 
       "status" : "Successfully Deployed", 
       "AppsCount" : "2" }' `

Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType "application/json" -Method Post -Body $body `
    -Uri “https://implementurihere"
```

Note: The above works if the `$body` is single line.

How to approach in such scenarios where we create a dynamic json , long file and feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example doesn't work because the **last line containing a backtick** which you have to omit.

You could use a [here string](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx) to define your JSON so you don't need to seperate each line by a backtick:

```
$body = 
@' 
    { "name" : "azurefunctionapp2email",
       "appname": "Applicationnamehere",
       "requestedBy" : "requestedby",
       "reqdate" : "requestdate", 
       "status" : "Successfully Deployed", 
       "AppsCount" : "2" }
'@
```

You could also consider to use a PowerShell hashtable to define your object which will allows you to use variables without the need of a format string:

```
$bodyObject = @{
    name = 'azurefunctionapp2email'
    appname = 'Applicationnamehere'
    requestedBy = 'requestedby'
    reqdate = 'requestdate'
    status = 'Successfully Deployed'
    AppsCount = '2'
}

$bodyObject | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks a ton.